# Second desktop other OS

Tags: operating-systems

I want to Dual Boot Windows 10 and Kali Linux.
That is not a problem, but I don't want to turn off my PC to get into Kali Linux.
I want that if I'm on Windows 10, Kali Linux is in the second desktop.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't run two operating systems at the same time unless one of the operating systems is installed in a virtual machine application such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

VirtualBox, and VMware allow you to install multiple operating systems on the same host machine. Both VM applications allow you to:

- Run more than one OS at the same time
- Switch between the OSs by switching to/from the VM application window.
- Except for logging out of the host OS, it's possible to start/stop/pause the OSs independently of each other.
- File sharing between OSs
- Allocate part of the hardware resources of the physical machine to the guest OS.
- Backup and restore the guest OS to a choice of restore points using snapshots.

Answer (score 2):

As @Karel said, provided you have a powerful enough system (4GB RAM & at least 2-cores) you can happily run Kali Linux as a virtual machine and have both systems running at the same time.

You have a few options when virtualizing Linux on a Windows host, VirtualBox by Oracle, VMWare is also another option. I think you can even get Linux to boot in Windows Hyper-V but I'm not entirely sure.

Remember though, You will not get full video acceleration for your virtual machine using a free virtualization tool.

For further reading, here is a great guide on how to get your system setup!
https://www.computersnyou.com/1626/how-to-install-kali-linux-in-virtual-machine-step-by-step/